# how do I force SSRS to run under a local server account. Trying to suppress password prompt

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have deployed some reports and my users wish to do away with the logon prompt when getting to the reports manager homepage.

I have an account which is local to the server and I want to run all of the SSRS site under the context of that account. This account is a "browser" in the reports site.

Prior to 2008, when SSRS site was still listed in IIS you could disable anonymous authentication and provide an account. All requests to the reports site would go in under that account which was configured with readonly access. It worked quite well this way. The only downside was that it made publishing new reports or doing updates a bit more difficult.

How do I accomplish this same thing using reporting services configuration tool? The service account and the execution account don't provide this functionality when I configured them.

Individually setting up users for access to the reports site is a maintenance sinkhole and my server is on someone else's domain so I don't have access to info like usernames and being able to create groups.

Also, I tried the "[anonymous access for 2012 reporting services](http://blog.quasarinc.com/ssrs/sql-server-reporting-services-2012-anonymous-access/)" steps and while this takes care of the logon prompt issue for me it also makes it to where users can delete data sources and reports entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular customer wanted no login prompts at all and agreed to pay support costs for re-deploying any reports which their workers may delete by accident.

To comply with their request I used the steps outlined in the "Anonymous access for 2012 reporting services" article referenced above.

Generally I would set up two accounts in the exact manner as Irb described. This is actually the first time that someone has not wanted that setup 0.o

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows authentication then you will need two accounts on the local server to satisfy your needs. One would be a "ReportUser" account and one would be a "ReportAdmin" account.

If you can provision or use two **existing** windows accounts for those roles then use SSRS manager to set the "ReportUser" as a browser user and "ReportAdmin" as an admin user in SSRS manager. Always deploy using the "ReportAdmin" user. The "ReportAdmin" could be the admin account for that box. You could deploy with that account.

Since you did not link the article you used to configure anon access I have no idea how your "ReportUser" is connecting.

Comment: I have the two accounts on the server as you describe above. The main issue when I set up anonymous access was that it treated all users as if they had "reportAdmin" permissions. I added the link to the article.

Comment: That custom security library is basically giving anyone with access to your SSRS server a free ride. If you have the code at least override and implement the Authorization() function to give everyone read-only access except credentials that you designate as an admin. If you do not do this I would at least make sure that server is not public facing.